# Query Performance & Tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, optimization

Want to optimize Oracle Query. Selection of one month data and it takes 24-26 secs approx to show data. Is it possible to optimize, refine it and it takes less time around 5-10 sec. Your feedback highly appreciated.

```
select eutrancellfdd,
       startdate,
       max(connected_users)
from
(select eutrancellfdd,
        startdate,
        starthour,
        Round((case when pmrrcconnlevsamp_sum = 0 then 0
                 else (pmrrcconnlevsum/pmrrcconnlevsamp_sum) end),0) as connected_users
 from tblericsson)
group by eutrancellfdd, startdate
Having startdate between to_date('03/01/2015','MM/DD/YYYY') 
  AND to_date('04/01/2015','MM/DD/YYYY')
  and eutrancellfdd='L0253401'
order by startdate asc;
```

Comment: Just a comment, HAVING is intended for aggregate function conditions, put regular column conditions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this query. 
In addition check if there are index on the columns eutrancellfdd and startdate.

```
select eutrancellfdd,
       startdate,
       max(Round((case when pmrrcconnlevsamp_sum = 0 then 0
                 else (pmrrcconnlevsum/pmrrcconnlevsamp_sum) end),0))
from
where startdate between to_date('03/01/2015','MM/DD/YYYY') 
      AND to_date('04/01/2015','MM/DD/YYYY')
      and eutrancellfdd='L0253401'
group by eutrancellfdd, startdate
order by startdate asc;
```